# Perl: How do I declare empty array refs in a new hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, warnings

I've got strict and warnings on, but it keeps complaining about the initialization of the following line:

```
$hash{$key} = ($row, [], [], [], '');
```

It warns for that single line:

```
"Useless use of private variable in void context"

"Useless use of anonymous list ([]) in void context" (3 times)
```

I am filling the data in later, but I want indexes 1, 2, 3 to be array references, and index 4 to be a string. I am accessing and filling the data like so:

```
$hash{$key}->[1]->[3] = 'Data';
$hash{$key}->[4] = $hash{$key}->[4] . 'More Data';
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not exactly sure how to make it right. (Also, I'm aware that that last line is redundant, could that also be summed up in a nicer way?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Elements of a hash can only be scalars, so you have to change your assignment to use the anonymous array constructor instead of parens:

```
$hash{$key} = [$row, [], [], [], ''];
```

See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information.

The line:

```
$hash{$key}->[4] = $hash{$key}->[4] . 'More Data';
```

could be written:

```
$hash{$key}->[4] .= 'More Data';
```

And finally, unless you like them, the `->` characters are implicit between subscript delimiters, so `$hash{$key}->[1]->[3]` means the same thing as `$hash{$key}[1][3]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to assign an array to a scalar value, you need to use brackets to create an anonymous array:

```
$hash{$key} = [$row, [], [], [], ''];
```

In your case, what you are attempting to do is interpreted as follows:

```
$row, [], [], [];
$hash{$key} = '';
```

Because you cannot assign a list of values to a scalar (single value variable). You can, like we did above, however, assign a *reference* to an anonymous array *containing* a list of values to a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it.

Remember that every hash and array value must be a scalar, so if you want a hash of arrays, you have to assign an array reference to your hash key. So:

```
$hash{$key} = [ $row, [], [], [], '' ];
```

is what you want.